# App crashes when using Settings.ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS in combination with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-10.0

I am trying to save network configurations with the following code on xamarin Android.

```
   private void AddWifi(string ssid, string psk)
        {
            var suggestions = new List<IParcelable>
            {
                new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                        .SetSsid(ssid)
                        .SetWpa2Passphrase(psk)
                        .Build()
            };
            var bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutParcelableArrayList(ExtraWifiNetworkList, suggestions);
            var intent = new Intent(ActionWifiAddNetworks);
            intent.PutExtras(bundle);
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodeConstants.WifiRequestCode);
        }
```

I am debugging on Android 12 devices and face frequent app crashes (Not always) when saving new networks. Although my app crashes, the debugger is attached to vs2022. The target framework of my app is Android 12.
I found some similar issues here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36094
and https://community.oneplus.com/thread/1353760

Visual Studio Output

```
[DecorView[]] onWindowFocusChanged hasWindowFocus false
[tWriterEnhance] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 119792(5287KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(164KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 5230KB/6974KB, paused 91us,85us total 54.456ms
[Activity] PerfMonitor: Slow Operation: Activity com.packagename/crc647e3ada291cd56112.MainActivity onDestroy took 627ms
[Choreographer] Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[Looper] PerfMonitor doFrame : time=0ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=683ms procState=-1 historyMsgCount=2 (msgIndex=2 wall=671ms seq=47927 late=20ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
```

Android studio Logcat

```
getRecentTasks: taskId=925   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.packagename/crc647e3ada291cd56112.MainActivity }
2023-03-09 21:50:10.680  1784-12912 ActivityTaskManager     system_server                        W    Force finishing activity com.packagename/crc647e3ada291cd56112.MainActivity
2023-03-09 21:50:11.859  7578-7578  tWriterEnhance          com...Inc.packagename  I  Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 119792(5287KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(164KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 5230KB/6974KB, paused 91us,85us total 54.456ms
2023-03-09 21:50:11.986  7578-7578  Activity                com...Inc.packagename  W  PerfMonitor: Slow Operation: Activity com.packagename/crc647e3ada291cd56112.MainActivity onDestroy took 627ms
2023-03-09 21:50:11.997  1784-12916 InputManager-JNI        system_server                        W  Input channel object '22029a1 com.packagename/crc647e3ada291cd56112.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
2023-03-09 21:50:12.008  7578-7578  Choreographer           com...Inc.packagename  I  Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2023-03-09 21:50:12.009  7578-7578  Looper                  com...Inc.packagename  W  PerfMonitor doFrame : time=0ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=683ms procState=-1 historyMsgCount=2 (msgIndex=2 wall=671ms seq=47927 late=20ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
2023-03-09 21:50:16.005  3068-3393  ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home                        E  getRecentTasks: taskId=925   userId=0   baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.packagename
```

Comment: What exception causes the crash?  What do the logs show?  Have you added any exception handling or crash reporting?

Comment: @Jason I have added the output debug log. Let me know if this is valid enough to find any sort of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new Xamarin.Android project to test your code.

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
        private void AddWifi(string ssid, string psk)
        {
            var suggestions = new List<IParcelable>
            {
                new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                        .SetSsid(ssid)
                        .SetWpa2Passphrase(psk)
                        .Build()
            };
            var bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutParcelableArrayList(Android.Provider.Settings.ExtraWifiNetworkList, suggestions);
            var intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionWifiAddNetworks);
            intent.PutExtras(bundle);
       //   this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.StartActivityForResult(intent,0); 
        }
       
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
              base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

              // Create your application here
              SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
              var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
              button.Click += delegate
              {
                  AddWifi("test123456", "test123456");
             };
        }
}
```

I tested both the `StartActivity` and `StartActivityForResult` method on the Android 12 emulator and the XiaoMi physical device with the Android 13. The network will be added successfully.

The result image:

[image]

Comment: Please make the SSID and password input fields and try saving the same SSID with a different password.  Also, the device should be running Android 10, 11, or 12.

Comment: The intent Settings.ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS was added in the Android 11. You can't run this api on the Android 10 device. @Santos

Comment: And I have added two edittext in my project to save the same SSID with a different password. It can be saved successfully. @Santos

Comment: The [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-save-network-passpoint-config) said : **On Android 11 (SDK level 30) and higher, apps can use the android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS intent to guide the user through adding one or more new saved networks or Passpoint configurations.** @Santos

Comment: @liyun-zhang-msft These are the steps I am using to get the issue:
1. Save a network and let the device connect to that network
2. Edit the password and save the network again
3. Repeat step 2

Comment: How did you connect to that network? Programmatically or use the system wifi manager? And which version of android device did you test on? @Santos

Comment: @iyun-zhang-msft I use Intent(Panel.ActionWifi) after saving the network and clicking the saved network to connect.
I am using Android 12 for testing.

Comment: When I edited the password and saved the network again. The connected wifi will break. And then I repeated this again. The wifi saved successfully but it will not connected because the password is incorrect. But it will not crash. @Santos

Comment: And you can try to use the breakpoint to check which line caused the crash. @Santos

Comment: @liyun-zhang-msft I think I found an exception from Loagcat. This is what the error message says: ThreadHelper: thread_callback() 145: More than one pending updates!!! This should not happen. MeterMgr should avoid this case.

Comment: Sorry for that I have no idea about this. I can't reproduce the error message with my project. @Santos

Comment: You are welcome. I regret I can't resolve the issue for you. @Santos